# Passing NSComboBox value that is inside a NSAlert Sheet

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, combobox, nsalert

I have a NSAlert Sheet that has a NSComboBox inside. How can i pass the combo box value when the user has pressed a button of the NSAlert?

code:

```
NSComboBox* comboBox = [[NSComboBox alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 150, 26)];
        [comboBox setTitleWithMnemonic:@"2"];

        for (int i=2; i<[array count]+1; i++){
            [comboBox addItemWithObjectValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
        }

        [comboBox setEditable:NO];

        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Okay"];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [alert setMessageText:@"Choose a number"];
        [alert setAccessoryView:comboBox];
        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:_window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(alertToChooseX:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];

- (void)alertToChooseX:(NSAlert *)alert returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    if (returnCode == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed Okay");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Describe *comboBox* in Your header file and after pushed button "*Okay*" take it's value like this:

in **.h**

```
NSComboBox *comboBox;
```

in **.m**

```
comboBox = [[NSComboBox alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 150, 26)];
[comboBox setTitleWithMnemonic:@"2"];
.... // Your all code goes here
```

```
- (void)alertToChooseX:(NSAlert *)alert returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    if (returnCode == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed Okay");

        NSLog(@"Selected ComboBox's String Value: %@", [comboBox stringValue]);
        NSLog(@"Selected ComboBox's Object Value: %@", [comboBox objectValueOfSelectedItem]);
        NSLog(@"Selected ComboBox's Item Index: %ld", [comboBox indexOfSelectedItem]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to release *comboBox* because it's allocating memory.

Comment: i was thinking on doing something like that, but i thought that there was a way to pass the value with the NSAlert. thank you! and btw, i'm using ARC so no release :P